# Calculate BJT common base amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, circuit-analysis

A single BJT common-base amplifier circuit with two inputs.

[image]

The nominal values for the transistor Q1,V<sub>BE</sub> and β are 0.7V and 80 respectively. Assume the base current can be neglected.

How to calculate the transconductance, gm of Q1 and Q2?
How to calculate the voltage gain of this amplifier?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you talk a little about what you already know about this circuit. What's the purpose of \$Q_2\$, for example? Why go to the trouble to add it? Does the input \$C_1\$ (there's another \$C_1\$ at the emitter leg of \$Q_1\$) serve a purpose? If so, what? How do you calculate gains when the other \$C_1\$ exists (the one in \$Q_1\$'s emitter leg, now?) Are you expected to compute the voltage gain with \$R_6\$ as the load? Etc. Talk about what how you think about this circuit.

Comment: The lecturer given this diagram to me, ask me to calculate, I don't know where to start, can you help?

Comment: Ryan, if you've no idea at all where to start with this diagram, then you also have no idea about simpler amplifier designs, either. Which means any answer would have to be very long. I'm not ready to go back that far, when writing. As a clue, have you even heard the terms "cascode," "Miller effect," "common emitter," or seen the variable equation, \$r_e=\frac{k T}{q I_C}\$?

Comment: Rather than me writing way too much, I'll just recommend you read the following (and pay particular attention when you get to page 13): https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese319/Lecture_Notes/Lec_11_Miller_Effect_08.pdf

Comment: Ryan, hopefully it helps. That document walks through some of the problems and the reason why the extra BJT adds value to the circuit. It also covers most of the details you'd care to know about. And now you can understand why I didn't want to attempt a duplication (and expansion) here given that you can't say anything much at all about your circuit. That's scary to me, while considering the idea of writing to you. It means way too much would be needed. Hopefully, that document will help bridge some gaps.

Comment: Hmm. Discounting base currents, \$ V_{B_1}\approx 5.7\: \textrm{V} \$ and so \$ I_{C_q}\approx 10\: \textrm{mA} \$ (reality is about a volt less.) Unloaded gain would normally be \$ \frac{560 \: \Omega}{510 \: \Omega} \$, discounting input loading, but the bypass cap means \$r_e = \frac{k T}{q I_C}\approx 2.6-2.8 \: \Omega\$ and \$ \frac{560 \: \Omega}{r_e} \approx 200 \$ . But that is cut in half because of the load. So 100 if the input voltage is tiny. \$ R_3 \$ is wrong as \$ 570 \: \textrm{mV} \$ isn't enough separation, so distortion from that, as well as \$Q_2\$ collector set too low.

Answer (score 0):

Once you read Jonk's ref. and understand it, you will notice similarity with other configurations of CC,CE,CB and learn to examine the impedance ratio Rc/Re using the transistor model.   DC operating point is computed 1st and then AC gain.

Gradually you Learn when you can simplify the results, by knowing the impedance at each I/O port for common CBE circuits after some practice. There is a compromise to accuracy on these assumptions and 10% may be acceptable in some cases.

I will do the shortcut approach but add some details not in the link, @jonk offered.

- Cap. impedance Zc is **not** a short circuit, but we assume this for AC analysis

  - where Zc = is 10% of R at 10x fB and 1% at 100x fB

    - for breakpoint fB= 1/(R*2πfC) of each bypass circuit
  - but 2 decades above Zc is now 1% of R
- β tolerance can be wide (>50%) but in this cascode design, there is low sensitivity to β
- Since Q1 emitter R4 is bypassed with C1 input thus \$Z_{in}=β~r_e\$

  - while \$r_e=kT / qI_c = 26mV/I_c \$ at room temp. (some folks use 25mV)
- the cascode design is a combination of CE and CB with a shared collector current so the voltage gain becomes the impedance ratios at collector of Q2 and emitter of Q1

  - Q1 load see the emitter of Q2 (Q2-e port) as the load at Q1-C
  - as the base of Q2 is bypassed with C1, the Q2-e impedance becomes \$r_e\$ , the same as Q1-e's output impedance so the Av of Q1 = \$r_{e2}/r_{e1}=1\$ for Ie~Ic
  - gain of Q2 as a Common Base (CB) is Av2=Rc/Re (non-inverting)

    - where Rc=R5//R6 and Re=re
- Now we need the DC current to compute Ic then re to get Av2

  - since base current loads the bias string of R1,R3,R2 we must estimate this effect.

    - for Q1 at base Zin = β(re+Re//Zc) but since Zc is bypass, is assumed 0
    - thus we get Zin = 80 * 560 = 40.8k (which is // R2).
    - almost the same base current drain occurs for Q2 as Q1 so these string of R's forcing the base voltages with some Zin loading effects.
- I will let you finish this homework on your own.
- final comment is that I prefer the emitter not to be bypassed as in the ref link but not this design as the overall gain is fairly low and large signal swings on the input cause distortion modulating Vbe.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLdtCQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>